# Google-play services API

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using android studio version 3.3. I wanted to put the dependency for

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.2'
```

However I keep 
getting an error that says failed to resolve. I have searched for the google API but failed to get it because I keep getting the

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
```

version. Can you please help me find a solution

Comment: try version `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0` instead .  I think `16.0.0` is the latest version. `16.0.2` is not yet released. Check this link for latest version https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location

Comment: it finally works. Thanks @pz64

Answer (score -1):

please add plugin of google into bottom of file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "package name"
         minSdkVersion 17
         targetSdkVersion 27
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
}

dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.2'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```